# No notification of new rep changes and they don't appear in the achievements dropdown

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications, achievements-dialog

As you can see on the [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348196/41686d6564?tab=reputation) on my profile, I received some up-/downvotes on my most recent post:

[image: Reaputation tab]

However, I did not get any notifications about them (the upvotes), nor do they even appear in the achievements dropdown (both up- and downvotes):

[image: Achievements dropdown]

#### Update:

They started to show up one by one (with a bit of a delay between each one). <s>The last one is still not shown.</s> Is this some kind of a caching issue?

Comment: Yes, this happens every day for an hour or two after UTC 00:00. I'm not sure what causes this though.